# How do I print the body of a node?

Tags: nodes

I am struggling to work out how to print a node body on a page.

I normally use something like this `print $node->field_manufacturer[0]['view'];` but I am unsure how to print the body of a node.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the whole structure and content of a node by writing:

```
<pre><?php print_r($node); ?></pre>
```

And then choosing what deems appropriate.

To print the node body, you should use `$node->content['body']['#value']`.

Comment: I have tried that. It brings up all the information. Specifically the custom field i have created. But i am unsure exactly how to print the body (a field that is always there).

Comment: Id answer my own questions but restrictions stopping me :#

this worked for me:
print $node->content['body']['#value'];

Answer (score 16):

For Drupal 7, a better style is to use field_get_items. E.g.:

```
<?php
  $body = field_get_items('node',$node, 'body');
  print $body[0]['value'];
?>
```

Answer (score 14):

Just try this for Drupal 7

```
<?php print render($content['body'])?>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Code-only answers are not the best ones possible. Could you explain how exactly this snippet is supposed to answer OPs issue?

Comment: `render` would be typically used inside `.tpl.php` templates to format the elements using layout information in the render array, see e.g. http://themery.com/dgd7/advanced-theming/render

Answer (score 10):

If `$node` is a node object obtained for example with `node_load()`, in Drupal 7 this is the structure of `$node->body`.

[image: screenshot]

The language set for the node I used in the screenshot is English, and the input format is full HTML. As far as I can see, the content of the body is always contained in the "und" index, whatever language has been set for the node.

In Drupal 6, `$node->body` is a string.

If you implemented `hook_nodeapi('view')` (Drupal 6) or `hook_node_view()` (Drupal 7) the content of the body is found, respectively, with `$node->content['body']['#value']`, and `$node->content['body'][0]['#markup']`.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

drupal 7 :

```
 <?php print $node->body['und'][0]['value'] ?>
```

Comment: LANGUAGE_NONE instead of und

Answer (score 0):

The following usually works:

```
<?php print $node->body['value']; ?>
```

Comment: Just tried that. No errors appear but neither does any content at all except for a ">" Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little late, but try the following, if you are using Drupal 6.

```
     <?php print $node->content['body']['#value'] ?>
```